# Windows 2008 R2 - how to optimise performance monitoring?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, performance, performance-monitoring, windows

It seems there are quite a few "default" monitoring threads running.

I have W2008R2 and when I opened Performance Monitor I can see 6 Event Trace Sessions in the System collector sets.

This is single application server and I need to make sure it is interrupted as little as possible. I dont really care about diagnostics and performance reports and I dont care about events.

**What trace sessions can I stop relatively safely?**

Comment: I would like to bump this. Correct me with respect to use policy.